# JS Promise .then().catch().then() chaining not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, core-js

I have a problem with the IE11... again

when i try to do some async task i do show a preloader in certain cases

so my code will be like

```
showPreloader()                 //to show my custom preloader
fetch(...)                      //initiate request to server
.then(...do some actionhere...)
.catch(console.log)             //log errors if any
.then(hidePreloader)            //hide my custom preloader
```

The deal here is that regardless if the promice fails or not i want second `.then()` to fire.
Kinda like `finally` clause in C#

And of course this works in any browser except IE. This beast breaks chain after the `catch()` if it happens and my preloader stays on indefinelty.
So is there a way to fix this so it works in IE as well?

**Edit 1:**
Using core-js library for the polyfills for IE

Comment: IE11 does not support promises. Make sure that you are providing a promise polyfill for IE11.

Comment: Are you using arrow functions on the callback?

Comment: Indeed, according to [CanIUse: promises](https://caniuse.com/#feat=promises), IE doesn't support them.  You need to use a library like Bluebird, or some other polyfill.

Comment: I'm using Core-JS as a polyfill for all IE issues, so is it that core-js implementation of promices doesnt match and causes this issue?

Comment: you should use .finally, not .then after .catch

Comment: @Max Thanks! This should be the answer!